# Параметры POST запроса в requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, requests

Получаю данные с API.
официальный мануал говорит это делать через http.client

```
import http.client
import mimetypes
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("mpstats.io")
payload = "{\"startRow\":0,\"endRow\":50,\"filterModel\":{},\"sortModel\":[{\"colId\":\"revenue\",\"sort\":\"desc\"}]}"
headers = {
  'X-Mpstats-TOKEN': token,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
conn.request("POST", "/api/wb/get/category?d1=2020-07-15&d2=2020-08-15&path=%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BC", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
```

Но с таким способом есть неудобство, так как данные получаю в bytes и надо декодить.
Хочу работать с requests, но параметры POST не применяются при запросе. Пробую следующий код

```
url_api = "http://mpstats.io/api/wb/get/category?d1=2020-07-13&d2=2020-08-11&path=%D0%96%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0"

headers = {
    'X-Mpstats-TOKEN': token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

payload = {
    "startRow" : 0,
    "endRow" : 300,
    "filterModel": {},
    "sortModel":[{"colId":"revenue","sort":"desc"}]
}
requests.post(url_api, headers=headers, data=payload).json()
```

Данные получаю но без учета payload. Пробовал payload давать строкой, эффект тот же. Что я делаю не так.

Comment: Насчет первого примера, вы можете сделать словарь и его в строку перевести, используя `json.dumps`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо параметра `data` используйте `json`:

```
requests.post(url_api, headers=headers, json=payload).json()
```

Разница в том, что:

- При указании `data` данные будут строиться как при отправке формы (http заголовок `Content-Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`)
- При указании `json` данные будут отправлены как строка в json (http заголовок `Content-Type = 'application/json'`)

Comment: не помогло. эффект тот же. Ответ есть, но без учета параметров

Comment: @Gremlin, там точно должен быть `http`, а не `https`? ``https://mpstats.io``. Еще проверьте, что у вас параметры запроса правильные, т.к. они отличаются для тех примеров из вопроса. Кст, эти параметры можно передавать в `params` как словарь, аналогично `json`

Comment: Даже в примере APi - `http.client.HTTPSConnection("mpstats.io")`

Comment: Спасибо! А слона то я и не приметил. Все работает.

Comment: @Gremlin, пожалуйста :)